# How to update 17.10 from a 17.04 VM whose disk needs partitioning with GParted that's not installed?

Tags: partitioning, updates, virtualbox, lubuntu, gparted

I need to update a 17.04 VM of lubuntu running in Oracle VirtualBox to 17.10. When I try the update, there was not enough free space despite removing any data files (the VM disk was only 10G, so not much space to reclaim).

I successfully grew the VirtualBox .vdi file to many more gigs, but following the steps [here](https://technology.amis.nl/2017/01/30/ubuntu-vm-virtualbox-increase-size-disk-make-smaller-exports-distribution/), I need to run `gparted`, which sadly is not on my 17.04 machine! It's a catch-22, because I can not install it since the (17.04) mirrors are no longer available anymore because it's EOL. Am I SOL?

I checked out 
 - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179577/how-do-i-resize-a-windows-partition-without-using-gparted but it seems to apply to Windows (and is really complex).

Is there a solution which doesn't require a fresh install? I'd like to keep my config of the 17.04 if possible.

---

Edit: As I already pointed out, I know 17.04 is EOL. [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815) is related but not a duplicate. I need to modify the partition of a drive to do an update, but can't get the software.

Answer (score 0):

Well this would work with any hypervisor provided you know how to attach an .iso image and change the boot order. Boot an .iso with gparted grow the partition and then the typical unsupported release upgrade procedure. I currenrtly don't have virtualbox installed so can't show screenshots.